# Buisness logic error handling in scala

Tags: scala, exception

I'm developing a web service using Scala and Play Framework 2.5. My application has typical layered architecture. I have the following classes: `model.User`, `repository.UserRepository`, `service.UserService` and `controllers.UserController` and I'm trying to a good way to handle buisness logic errors without using `Exception`.

Consider the following case: a request for registration a new user was received. There are two parameters in the request body: `email` and `password`. These parameters are fed to `UserService#registerUser` which checks if the email is valid and if user with such email already exists. My solution is to make `UserService#registerUser` return as a result an `Either[BuisnessFailure, Int]` object. `BuisnessFailure` is a trait and is inherited by `WrongEmailFormatFailure` and `UserAlreadyExistFailure`.
If the email is not valid, `UserService#registerUser` returns `Left(WrongEmailFormatFailure)`. If a user with such email already exists, `UserService#registerUser` returns `Left(UserAlreadyExistFailure)`. And in case of success, `UserService#registerUser` returns `Right(userRepository.create(User(email, password))`.Afterwards, in `controllers.UserController` I can handle this case using pattern matching and send an appropriate response.

So, is this approach good enough to handle similar cases? Please, find my code below:

User:

```
package model
case class User(email: String, password: String)
```

UserRepository:

```
package repository

import model.User

class UserRepository {
  def create(user: User): Int = ???
  def find(email: String): Option[User] = ???
}
```

UserService:

```
package service

import model.User
import repository.UserRepository
import util.{BuisnessFailure, UserAlreadyExistFailure, WrongEmailFormatFailure}

class UserService {
  private val userRepository: UserRepository = ???
  def registerUser(email: String, password: String): Either[BuisnessFailure, Int] = {
    if (userAlreadyExists(email))
      Left(UserAlreadyExistFailure)
    else
      if (!isEmailValid(email))
        Left(WrongEmailFormatFailure)
      else
        Right(userRepository.create(User(email, password)))

  }
  private def isEmailValid(email: String): Boolean = ???
  private def userAlreadyExists(email: String): Boolean = ???
}
```

UserController:

```
package controller

import service.UserService
import util.{UserAlreadyExistFailure, WrongEmailFormatFailure}

class UserController extends play.api.Controller {
  private val userService = new UserService
  def signUp() = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
    //obtaining email and password parameters from request body
    val email = ???
    val password = ???
    userService.registerUser(email, password) match {
      case Left(WrongEmailFormatFailure) => // send 400 code and appropriate error message
      case Left(UserAlreadyExistFailure) => // send 400 code and appropriate error message
      case Right(_) => // send response with 200 code
    }
  }
}
```

BuisnessFailure:

```
package util

sealed trait BuisnessFailure
case object UserAlreadyExistFailure extends BuisnessFailure
case object WrongEmailFormatFailure extends BuisnessFailure
```

Comment: Good question, but it would be more appropriate on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jubobs  Thanks for the link. I haven't ever heard about  softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I would make validation another service, so it is more testable and reusable

Comment: @Jubobs when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat I wasn't suggesting cross-posting, but deleting the question from SO and posting it instead on Software Engineering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what we've done regarding error handling for one of our biggest projects and we didn't have any problem. `Either` should be used exactly like that. `Left` for errors and `Right` for results.

- It's typesafe
- No need to worry about concurrency
- The code is scalable and maintainable

The only point is that, as most of Scala applications are non-block (async) people would use `Future[Either[Error, Int]]` rather than `Either[Error, Int]`. But still, it's OK, as whenever you decided to go for non-blocking you can easily wrap `Either` inside a `Future` and as I told you, no worries about concurrency issues.